# Выплывающий блок по клику на ссылку

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, блок

Всем привет. Есть такая проблема.
На сайте есть блоки, которые будут выпадать.

```
<div class="li_shedule" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <a href="#" id="description_courses">Курсы 1</a><br /> --кликаем сюда
    <div class="description_info" style="display:none; background-color: #f8f8f8; border:1px solid #cccccc; padding:10px; border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;">--выпадает этот блок
    1
    </div>
<a href="#" id="description_courses">Курсы 2</a><br />--кликаем сюда
    <div class="description_info" style="display:none; background-color: #f8f8f8; border:1px solid #cccccc; padding:10px; border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;">--выпадает этот блок
    1
    </div>
<a href="#" id="description_courses">Курсы 3</a><br />--кликаем сюда
        <div class="description_info" style="display:none; background-color: #f8f8f8; border:1px solid #cccccc; padding:10px; border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;">--выпадает этот блок
        1
        </div>
    </div>
```

Написал вот такой Jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i=0;
    $('#description_courses').click(function() {
            $('.description_info').slideToggle('fast');

      });

});
</script>
```

Работает не совсем корректно. Кликаем по первому - выпадает все сразу, а по второму не работает.

Как решить эту проблему? Пример работы на [сайте](http://1s-legko.kz/index.php/schedule).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@duddeniska](/users/3435/duddeniska), тема вечная: **один ID - у одного элемента** и без вариантов! Для нескольких используют классы. И используйте **this**, для определения нужного раскрывающегося блока, плюс ко всему разметка не удобная ([проверяем](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/nbod2xtt/)):

```
var links = $('.description_courses');
links.click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(links).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: Работает, ты мозг! Ставлю Плюс. 
p/s что означает вот это

    $(this).nextUntil(links).slideToggle('fast');

Comment: @duddeniska, 

    $('selector_form').nextUntil('selector_until');

находит все элементы, лежащие начиная от элемента **selector_form** (*в вашем случае, ссылка по которой кликнули*) и заканчивая **selector_until** (*у вас - следующая ссылка*). Но я бы изменил разметку, т.к. если вы забудете и добавите какой-нибудь элемент между ссылками, то он так же попадёт "под раздачу". Кстати, элемент <br> уже входит в их число, правда он пока не влияет на результат.